# python asyncio.start_server() .Почему после одного ответа сервак отключает пользователя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, asyncio

Писал сервер для чата при помощи модуля asyncio, но после ответа клиенту сервак отключал пользователя. Как это пофиксить?

версия python 3.8.0

```
import asyncio
import socket
import json


class Server():
    def __init__(self,host,port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.clients = {}

    async def start_server(self):
        server = await asyncio.start_server(self.accept_conection,
                                            self.host,self.port,
                                            family = socket.AF_INET,
                                            flags = socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        await server.serve_forever()

    async def accept_conection(self,reader,writer):
        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
        print(addr)
        sock = reader._transport._sock
        response = await self.read_response(reader)
        print(response)
        if response.decode():
            data = json.loads(response)
            self.clients[addr] = data['nick']
            await self.broadcast_response(sock,data['msg'])


    async def read_response(self,reader):
        while True:
            request = await reader.read(1024)

            if request:
                return request
            else:
                return None

    async def broadcast_response(self,sock,msg):
        for client in self.clients:
            print(self.clients[client])
            response = f"{self.clients[client]}:{msg}"
            sock.sendto(bytes(response,'utf8'),client)
            self.clients.pop(client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server('localhost',5000)
    asyncio.run(server.start_server())
```

Answer (score 2):

Для тех у кого еще имеется такой вопрос. Ответ кроется в зацикливании и ожидании данных, пока не закроется соединение. Собственно говоря, автор вопроса решил задачу, только не отметил его.

```
async def read_response(self,reader):
    while True:
        request = await reader.read(1024)

        if request:
            return request
        else:
            return None
```